# how to select root class variable into another class in css

Tags: css

```
<style>
    :root product6 {
        --width:435px;
    }
    :root .size1 {
        --scale: 0.8;
    }
    :root .size2 {
        --scale: 0.7;
    }

    .productDiv {transform:scale(--scale);}
</style>

<div class="product6 size1"></div>
```

This is working well if I give classes inside div class attr...showing my div scaled 0.8 and width 435px

But how can I select size1 class inside css syntax under stylesheet

```
.productDivResponsive {width:435px;transform:scale(???)}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot, CSS is not a prgamming language and variables obey to the Cascade, so you need to use Class like you did, you cannot pick random variable and use them like you want

Comment: also this `transform:scale(--scale)`  need to be `transform:scale(var(--scale))`

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables in root element (`:root`), so that they are available everywhere. Then define classes and ids, that use those variables in any way you see fit.

*(If you want a narrower scope, you can also define your vars for another element. You do not necessarily have to use `:root`. Have a look at the special section in my example.)*

```css
/* define vars for everywhere, as everything inherits from root */
:root {
  --width: 100px;
  --height: 100px;
  --scale-1: 0.8;
  --scale-2: 0.6;
  --scale-3: 0.4;
  --c-green: #3d9970;
  --c-red: #ff4136;
  --c-blue: #0074d9;
}

/* define vars for a specific part of your page, overriding root in this example */
#special {
  --c-green: #01FF70;
  --c-red: #f012be;
  --c-blue: #7fdbff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

section {
  margin: 10px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.7);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3))
}

.scale-1 {
  transform: scale(var(--scale-1));
}

.scale-2 {
  transform: scale(var(--scale-2));
}

.scale-3 {
  transform: scale(var(--scale-3));
}

#product-2 {
  background-color: var(--c-green);
}

#product-3 {
  background-color: var(--c-red);
}

#product-4 {
  background-color: var(--c-blue);
}

#product-5 {
  background-color: var(--c-green);
}

#product-6 {
  background-color: var(--c-red);
}

#product-7 {
  background-color: var(--c-blue);
}

/* within scope of #special, colors are different: */

#product-10 {
  background-color: var(--c-blue);
}

#product-11 {
  background-color: var(--c-red);
}

#product-12 {
  background-color: var(--c-green);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div id="product-1" class="product">1</div>
    <div id="product-2" class="product scale-1">2</div>
    <div id="product-3" class="product scale-2">3</div>
    <div id="product-4" class="product scale-3">4</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="product-5" class="product scale-3">5</div>
    <div id="product-6" class="product scale-2">6</div>
    <div id="product-7" class="product scale-1">7</div>
    <div id="product-8" class="product">8</div>
  </section>
  <section id="special">
    <div id="product-9" class="product scale-2">9</div>
    <div id="product-10" class="product scale-2">10</div>
    <div id="product-11" class="product scale-2">11</div>
    <div id="product-12" class="product scale-2">12</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Daniel...I am checking and trying your answer

Answer (score 0):

> *This is working well if I give classes inside div class attr...showing my div scaled 0.8 and width 435px*

The code provided cannot possibly work, it's syntactically erroneous.

> *But how can I select size1 class inside css syntax under stylesheet?*

Addition of question mark was my edit.

CSS is static, hard coded, so just write it in just as you have with the rest of your CSS. I hope you are not asking how to dynamically manipulate CSS on the stylesheet because you need to grasp the advanced concepts dealing with CSS and working knowledge of JavaScript.

---

#### Demo

**Note:** Details are commented in demo

```css
/*
Declare CSS variables
:root is the best selector to use because all descendants
will have access to them.

--=These are VALUES ONLY=--
They cannot be assigned to a selector directly
They can only be assigned to a property
propert: value is assigned to a selector
*/

:root {
  --w435: 435px;
  --scX070: 0.7;
  --scX120: 1.2;
}

.box {
  background: gold;
  color: blue;
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 20px auto;
  min-height: 30px;
  /* 
  This is the proper syntax when assigning the value of a
  CSS variable to a property
  ${selector} {${property}: var(--${CSSVar});}
     .box     {    width:      var(--w435);  }
  */
  width: var(--w435);
}

.size1 {
  transform: scaleX(var(--scX070));
}

.size2 {
  transform: scaleX(var(--scX120));
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class="box size1"></div>
<div class="box size2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use this code I can make that I need...but I don't want to write classes twice...Problem is I want to use divs somewhere static somewhere responsive...

```
<style>
    :root .product6 {
        --width:435px;
    }
    :root .size1 {
        --scale: 0.8;
    }
    :root .size2 {
        --scale: 0.7;
    }

    .productDiv {transform:scale(--scale);}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    :root {
        --scale:0.8;
    }
    .productDivResponsive {transform:scale(var(--scale));}
}

@media (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 1360px) {
    :root {
        --scale:0.7;
    }
    .productDivResponsive {transform:scale(var(--scale));}
}

</style>

<div class="product6 productDiv"></div> <!-- This one static and scaling my div 0.8 -->
```

and want to make it responsive somewhere in my page with writing code something like that;

```
<div class="productDivResponsive"></div>
```

my productDivResponsive div must be scaled according to my media queries...

how can I remove repeating root class variables?

I hope I can explain what I need...Possible??